# Adding row and column to matrix at the same time

Tags: r, row

I want to add a column with values [1, 1, 0] to a matrix with dim `(2×2)` and a row with values [1, 1, 0] to produce a matrix with dim `(3×3)`.

```
# Create the original matrix
original_matrix <- matrix(c(7, 2, 3, 5), nrow = 2)

# Add a column with values [1, 1, 0]
modified_matrix <- cbind(original_matrix, c(1, 1, 0))

# Add a row with values [1, 1, 0]
final_matrix <- rbind(modified_matrix, c(1, 1, 0))
```

I used the cbind function to add columns and the rbind function to add rows. Is there any way to do it in one go?

Comment: This was indeed just an example. My actual objective is to add both a column and a row to the weight matrix to satisfy the condition t(W) * I = 1. I appreciate your assistance, and the function you provided is working, which aligns with what Paulbouu also mentioned. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can avoid creating `modified_matrix` by doing this:

```
final_matrix <- rbind(cbind(original_matrix, c(1, 1)), c(1, 1, 0))
```

But if you want the answer in a general case you'll have to manually "cut" one of your vectors.